# Enforce Type Alias in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, declarative, type-alias

How might one go about aliasing a type in VB.NET or C# such that when the alias is used as an argument type in a function, accidentally using the not aliased type is an error?

i.e.

```
Imports AccessSpecifier = System.String

Module Accessors
    Delegate Function IoOper(ByRef strm As System.IO.Stream) As Action
    Public Function accessMethod(ByRef spec As AccessSpecifier) As IoOper
        ' implementation
        ' ...
    End Function
End Module

Module Main
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim spec As AccessSpecifier = New AccessSpecifier(CType("READ_WRITE", Char()))
        Dim val = Accessors.accessMethod(spec)
        System.Console.WriteLine(val.GetType())
        Dim shouldFail = Accessors.accessMethod("FAIL_ME")
        System.Console.WriteLine(shouldFail.GetType())
    End Sub
End Module
```

Or perhaps is there a better way to go about this?

Overall, I'm wanting the IDE to force me to know what I'm doing if I'm throwing `Ints` around to mean `Flag`s, or `State`s and `Strings` around to mean `Name`s, `Property`s and `Record`s.

Help?

Comment: Just put Option Strict On at the top of the source code file.

Comment: `Option Strict` prevents implicit conversion. There's no conversion happening here because the types are identical.

Comment: Erm, no, an Integer is not identical to a String.  Isn't that what you tried to avoid?  With Option Strict Off, the compiler is happy to generate the code to *try* to convert a string to an integer.  With a kaboom at runtime when that can't work.  Otherwise the kind of dynamic typing that vb programmers tend to like in the language.  Consider C# as a language that has very strict typing.

Comment: Oh! Hehe, no, sorry. I was referring to my example above. `AccessSpecifier` aliases `System.String`, and I'm wanting to warn/error on passing a `string` literal, or regular `string` variable.

Comment: You are missing my point, although there's some serious possibility of me not getting yours.  The vb.net compiler already has the ability to enforce strict typing.  Use the Option.  You are looking for another way to do it that doesn't work.  Because the alias is just a name substitution that doesn't alter the fundamental compiler rules.  So don't use it, it doesn't solve your problem.  Use the Option.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for the strictness and safety having specific types for specific purposes, and trying to avoid the code footprint bloat as well as the object overhead of eliminating value types. The increased clutter that goes along with it nearly negates the clarity benefits. Guess I'm looking for something VB can't provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never liked Type aliasing in .NET.  It makes for imprecise code and it is not immediately clear what is happening.  As in your example, when an individual went looking for the AccessSpecifier.vb file (or class) they would not find it.

Also, Aliasing only works within YOUR project and only within a single code file.  So you would have to define that alias in all the various code files where it was to be used.

A better (as in easier to read, easier to maintain, and more clear of intent) option is to create a class and overload the type conversion operators for automatic conversion to/from String.  In this manner you retain your ability to use your new class as if it were a String, but you gain your strict type checking.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about implicit conversions in the .NET framework. Thank you for that.